# Frameless BrowserWindow in macOS 10.13 (Beta) still displays a title bar

Tags: macos, electron, macos-high-sierra

I updated my macOS to version 10.13 Beta, and feels superior than ever before. However when I started up my Electron app, I immediately noticed that my frameless window, which worked perfectly under 10.12, displayed a title bar. Here's a picture:

[image: Undesired Behavior]

Notice the grey bar on the top. The desired behavior would be no grey bar on top. I'm on the latest Electron version at the time of writing (1.6.11) and latest version of Node. Can someone explain why this is happening, and possibly a work-around?

Here's my code that creates this `BrowserWindow`:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    left:        electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize.width - 30,
    width:       30, 
    height:      (global.sharedObject.courseCount + 2) * 18 - 2 + 14,
    transparent: true,
    resizable:   false,
    frame:       false, 
    show:        false, 
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    hasShadow:   false
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `titleBarStyle: 'hidden'` instead of `frame. false`?

Comment: @RoyalBingBong Sadly, it doesn't work.

Comment: You should file a Radar about this. If you can provide a small project that demonstrates this issue chances are way better that Apple will fix it.

Comment: I notice the same issue with my App on OSX 10.13 (release, not beta). In fact I lost control on the way some items are drawn (textField background color) at top of the window. I also noticed a new option in Xcode Attributes Inspector for NSWindow "Transparent title bar" But that doesn't help.